# C# Active Directory FindByIdentity Fails

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

Ok,  I have Active Directory lookups working fine when a user enters their user pass.  Now I am trying to adapt that code to allow for single sign-on.  What I have:

- IIS App Pool set to Network User
- Anonymous Auth turned off in IIS
- web config setup with  and

Code:

```
WindowsIdentity userIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"))
{
this.User = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userIdentity.Name);
```

The FindByIdentity fails with one of these errors depending on different context changes:

Unknown error (0x8000500c) Stack:    at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()

Unknown error (0x80005000) Stack:    at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()

things I have tried include, adding the container name to the context lookup in the form of "cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" and "dc=mydomain,dc=com" as well as including or not including ContextOptions.Negotiate either with the container set or the container passed as null.

Just not sure where to go next.  I need all of the Group Names for the user, and I have tried just getting the group names with UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups or whatever that one is, but it fails with the same PopulateList() error as above.

Am I missing something simple?   If I provide the user/pass in the context creation it works fine so I am not sure if I have to create an AD user in order to query AD but that is not a great option if at all.

I have read all the posts regarding this and cannot seem to get past it.

Answer (score 0):

Error `0x8000500c` means `Active Directory Datatype Cannot be Converted to/from a Native DS Datatype`.

This problem is caused because `WindowsIdentity.Name` is in the format `DOMAIN\USERNAME` which is not a valid `SamAccountName`.

Seems like you are trying to get the `UserPrincipal` for the current user, if so just use `UserPrincipal.Current`.

Comment: so I changed it to do:  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;  and I am getting this error even though the Current says it returns a UserPrincipal:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' 
  to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'. Stack:    
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()